# Real-time Data Visualization with XYChart Library

Tags: java, eclipse, visualization, simulator

I am utilizing the XYChart library in Java to receive real-time data via a socket connection, dynamically visualizing three point curves on the chart. However, I have a specific requirement to modify the second point curve and display it as a connected line while keeping the other two curves unchanged. Despite the XYChart library automatically handling the positioning of the points to create three curves, I am seeking a way to customize the visualization of the second curve by converting it into a connected line.

I am unable to identify the mid curve because XYChart visualize shape dynamically. Is it better way to apply k-means algorithm to separate all near-by points and then identify mid curve to update it??

```
 * 
 */
/**
 * 
 */
package flta.plotting;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

import org.knowm.xchart.BitmapEncoder;
import org.knowm.xchart.BitmapEncoder.BitmapFormat;
import org.knowm.xchart.QuickChart;
import org.knowm.xchart.SwingWrapper;
import org.knowm.xchart.XChartPanel;
import org.knowm.xchart.XYChart;
import org.knowm.xchart.XYChartBuilder;
import org.knowm.xchart.XYSeries;
import org.knowm.xchart.XYSeries.XYSeriesRenderStyle;
import org.knowm.xchart.style.Styler.LegendPosition;
import org.knowm.xchart.style.markers.SeriesMarkers;

/**
 * @author Mo
 *
 */
public class Main {

    /**
     * 
     */
    public Main() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        ////////////////////////////////////////
        //Declare socket variables and establish the connection
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null; 
        Socket clientSocket = null;
         
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5001); // 4447 is port number
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); // blocks and listen until a connection is made. 
            System.out.println("Connection Accepted");
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("IOException");
        }
        
        
//      //Write to the socket: 
//      BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream())); 
//      wr.write("My Messages!");
//      wr.flush(); // flushes the stream
        
        double[] xData;
        double[] yData;
        xData = new double[] { 0.0, 9000.0 };
        yData = new double[] { 0.0 ,0.0};
        double[][] initdata = {xData, yData};
        // Create Chart
//      final XYChart chart =
//          QuickChart.getChart(
//              "Predicted Path", "X", "Y", "y(x)", initdata[0], initdata[1]);
        XYChart chart = new XYChartBuilder().width(800).height(800).title("Horizontal View").xAxisTitle("X").yAxisTitle("Y").build();
        XYChart chart2 = new XYChartBuilder().width(800).height(800).title("Vertical Clearance").xAxisTitle("X").yAxisTitle("Y").build();
        chart.getStyler().setDefaultSeriesRenderStyle(XYSeriesRenderStyle.Scatter);
        chart.getStyler().setChartTitleVisible(false);
        chart.getStyler().setMarkerSize(6);
        chart.getStyler().setXAxisMax(2000.0);
        chart.getStyler().setYAxisMax(2000.0);
        chart.getStyler().setXAxisMin(-2000.0);
        chart.getStyler().setYAxisMin(-2000.0);
        
        //chart2.getStyler().setDefaultSeriesRenderStyle(XYSeriesRenderStyle.Scatter);
        chart2.getStyler().setChartTitleVisible(false);
        chart2.getStyler().setMarkerSize(6);
        chart2.getStyler().setXAxisMax(1500.0);
        chart2.getStyler().setYAxisMax(1000.0);
        chart.getStyler().setXAxisMin(-3000.0);
        chart.getStyler().setYAxisMin(-1000.0);
        chart2.getStyler().setAxisTicksLineVisible(true);
        
        XYSeries series = chart.addSeries("y(x)", initdata[0], initdata[1]);
        series.setMarker(SeriesMarkers.CIRCLE);
        
        XYSeries series2 = chart2.addSeries("y(x)", initdata[0], initdata[1]);
        series2.setMarker(SeriesMarkers.CIRCLE);
        
        XYSeries series3 = chart2.addSeries("ground", initdata[0], initdata[1]);
        series3.setMarker(SeriesMarkers.DIAMOND);
        series3.setLineColor(Color.red);
        series3.setXYSeriesRenderStyle(XYSeriesRenderStyle.Step);

        
        // Show it
        final SwingWrapper<XYChart> sw = new SwingWrapper<XYChart>(chart);
        final SwingWrapper<XYChart> sw2 = new SwingWrapper<XYChart>(chart2);
        sw.displayChart();
        sw2.displayChart();
        //Read from the socket
        String inputLine; 
        System.out.println("Reading");
        double PlanePosX=0;
        double PlanePosY=0;
        int j=1;
        String[] points;
        while (true)
        {
            try {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream())); 
                while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
                    System.out.println(inputLine);
                    if (inputLine.equals("env"))
                    {
                        inputLine = in.readLine();
                        points=inputLine.split(",");
                        xData=new double[points.length];
                        yData=new double[points.length];
                        for(int i=0; i<points.length; i++)
                        {
                            String[] PointsSplit=points[i].split(" ");
                            xData[i]=Double.parseDouble(PointsSplit[0]);
                            yData[i]=Double.parseDouble(PointsSplit[1]);
                            System.out.println(xData[i]+" , "+yData[i]+";");
                        }
                        chart2.updateXYSeries("y(x)", xData, yData, null); sw2.repaintChart();
                    }else {
                        points=inputLine.split(",");
                        xData=new double[points.length];
                        yData=new double[points.length];
                        double[] zData=new double[points.length];
                        double[] distanceData=new double[points.length];
                        for(int i=0; i<points.length; i++)
                        {
                            
                            String[] PointsSplit=points[i].split(" ");
                            if (i==0)
                            {
                                PlanePosX=Double.parseDouble(PointsSplit[0]);
                                PlanePosY=Double.parseDouble(PointsSplit[1]);
                                //System.out.println("Center "+PlanePosX+" , "+PlanePosY+";");
                            }
                            xData[i]=Double.parseDouble(PointsSplit[0])-PlanePosX;
                            yData[i]=Double.parseDouble(PointsSplit[1])-PlanePosY;
                            
                            zData[i]=Double.parseDouble(PointsSplit[2]);
                            distanceData[i]=Double.parseDouble(PointsSplit[3]);
                            //System.out.println("result of: "+PointsSplit[0]+" , "+PlanePosX+";");
                            System.out.println(xData[i]+" , "+yData[i]+";");
                        }
                        chart.updateXYSeries("y(x)", xData, yData, null); sw.repaintChart();
                        //plot the elevation
                        chart2.updateXYSeries("ground", distanceData, zData, null); sw2.repaintChart();
                    }
                    
                
                    if (clientSocket.isInputShutdown())
                        System.out.println("Exception");
                    //isReachable(null,0,200);
                }
            }catch (SocketException ei) {
                System.out.println("Connection Lost");
                try {
                    serverSocket.close();
                    clientSocket.close();
                    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5001); // 4447 is port number
                    clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); // blocks and listen until a connection is made. 
                    System.out.println("Connection Accepted");
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("IOException");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Other Things");
                e.printStackTrace();
                continue;
            }
        }
        ///////////////////////////////////////
        
        
    }

     private static double[][] getSineData(double phase) {

            double[] xData = new double[100];
            double[] yData = new double[100];
            for (int i = 0; i < xData.length; i++) {
              double radians = phase + (2 * Math.PI / xData.length * i);
              xData[i] = radians;
              yData[i] = Math.sin(radians);
            }
            return new double[][] {xData, yData};
          }
}
```